# Show a $G$-set $(X,\mu: X\times G\to X)$ has continuous $\mu$ iff for each $x\in X$ its isotropy group is open.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, group-actions, topological-groups, topos-theory

This is **Exercise I.6(a)** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]".* According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcategory-theory%5D+isotropy+), it is new to MSE.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be a topological group and $\mathbf{B}G$ the category of continuous $G$-sets${}^\dagger$. Let $G^\delta$ be the same group $G$ with the discrete topology. So $\mathbf{B}G^\delta=\mathbf{Sets}^{{G^\delta}^{{\rm op}}}$ is a category as considered in the [previous exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3540514/104041). Let $i_G: \mathbf{B}G\to \mathbf{B}G^\delta$ be the inclusion functor.
>
> (a) Prove that a $G$-set $(X,\mu:X\times G\to X)$ is in the image of $i_G$, *i.e.*, that $\mu$ is continuous${}^\dagger$, iff for each $x\in X$ its *isotropy* subgroup $$I_x=\{ g\in G\mid x\cdot g=x\}$$ is an open subgroup of $G$.

*(I'm not sure what an open subgroup is, unless it's just a subgroup $H\le G$ such that $H$, when considered as $H\subseteq G$, is open in the topology of $G$; I couldn't find a definition)*

### Thoughts:

Let $G$ be a topological group with topology $\tau$, and $(X,\mu: X\times G\to X)$ a $G$-set.

$(\Leftarrow)$

Suppose, for all $x\in X$, that $I_x$ is an open subgroup of $G$. Then, since $\mu$ is a right $G$-action, we have, for each $g'\in G$, that $(x\cdot g)\cdot_\mu g'=x\cdot_\mu g'=m$ for some $m\in X$ dependent on $x$ and $g'$.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

$(\Rightarrow)$

<strike>Assume $\mu$ is continuous. Then, for any open $U\subseteq G$ with respect to the discrete topology, we have $\mu^{-1}(U)$ in the topology $\tau$. But every subset of $G$ is open in the discrete topology; in particular, for each $x\in X$, $\mu^{-1}(I_x)$ is in $\tau$.</strike>

(See $\dagger$ below.)

I'm not sure what to do from here on out.

---

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: What is the topology on $X$? Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228265/104041) will make explicit what is meant by "$\mu$ is continuous".

Comment: You have the definition of an open subgroup correct.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228240/stabilisers-of-group-action-open-imply-the-action-is-continuous

Comment: What topology do you want to put on $X$ in order to be able to talk about a continous action $G\times X \to X$ ?

Comment: That's a good question, @jeanmfischer; I'm not sure. Perhaps I missed out some details. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps "$\mu$ is continuous" is an abuse of language for "$(X\times G\to X,\mu)$ is in the image of the inclusion functor $i_G$", @jeanmfischer. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should try with the discrete topology on $X$, then the open sets of $X\times G$ should be easy to describe, and the preimages of the singletons on $X$ too. Then what is the image of that continous action under $i_G$ ?

Comment: That's a sensible suggestion. Thank you. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228265/104041), @jeanmfischer, however. Allusions are made as to what it means.

Comment: I think the problem can be traced back, too, to the definition of $\mathbf{B}G$ as given in the question, @jeanmfischer.

Comment: You should indeed take the discrete topology, otherwise there are [counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103498/is-a-topological-group-action-continuous-if-and-only-if-all-the-stabilizers-are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G^{\delta}$ be the topological group $G$ but with the discrete topology. There is a continous group morphism $\iota_G : G^{\delta} \to G$.

Consider a topological group $H$, then denote by $H-\text{Cont}$, the category of continous left $H$-actions, i.e. spaces $X$ and $\mu : H \times X\to X$ continous action. Consider $f:H\to K$ a morphism of topologial groups, there is a functor 
$$
f^* : K-\text{Cont} \to H-\text{Cont}
$$

The morphism $\iota_G$, gives then a functor 
$$
(\iota_G)^* : G-\text{Cont} \to (G^\delta)-\text{Cont}
$$
Given a $G$-set, $(X, G\times X \to X)$ (where here the action is just a map of sets, no topology of $G$ involved) we can form a $G^\delta$-space if we give $X$ the discrete topology. Modulo verifications on what happens to morphisms, there is a functor
$$
\Delta : G-\text{Set} \to (G^\delta)-\text{Cont}
$$
One interpretation of your question is :

> For any $G$-set $X$ is it true that $\Delta(X)$ is in the essential image of $(\iota_G)^*$ if and only if for any $x \in X$, $I_x$ is open in the topology of $G$ ?

If for all $x\in X$, $I_x$ are open then $\mu^{-1}(\{x\}) = I_x\times \{x\}$ which is open in the product topology of $G\times X$, where $X$ has the discrete topology. So we have an object of $G-\text{Cont}$, and this object is sent to $\Delta(X)$ by the functor $(\iota_G)^*$.

On the other hand suppose that $\Delta(X)$ is in the image of $(\iota_G)^*$, there is some space $Y$ and a continuous $G$-action $\nu : G\times Y \to Y$, such that $(\iota_G)^*(Y) = \Delta(X)$. Since $(\iota_G)^*$ doesn't change the underlying space and the underlying action, $Y$ should be $X$ with the discrete topology and $\nu$ is $\mu$, then $\mu^{-1}(\{x\}) = I_x\times \{x\}$ should be open for every $x\in X$, so $I_x$ is open in $G$.

Another question is the following

> How to characterise the essential image of $(\iota_G)^*$ ?

Let $X$ be a space and $\mu : G^\delta \times X \to X$ a continous action on $X$. The question is equivalent to : under what conditions is $\mu$ continous map $G\times X\to X$, with $G$ having the topology we started with ?

Define for all $U$ open in $X$, $I_U = \{g\in G, \forall x \in U, g\cdot x \in U\}$. I think is not to difficult now to see that $(X,\mu)$ is in the image of $(\iota_G)^*$ if and only if, for all $U\subseteq X$ open, $I_U$ is open in $G$.

Comment: Thank you. I've changed your $i_G$ to $\iota_G$ to distinguish it from the $i_G$ in the question. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I get $\mu^{-1}(\{x\})=\{(g,y) \mid yg=x \}$ but you say $\mu^{-1}(\{x\})=I_x\times\{x\}$. Why? Can't I have another $y\in X, g\in G$ with $y\neq x$ and $yg=x$?

Comment: Yes you are right, then your set is the union of copies of I_x for every point in the orbit of x

Comment: Which is then still open in the product topology